# Error saving in SQL Server if system datetime format is changed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I am importing data from an Excel file into SQL Server using a C# app. My sheet contains some datetime columns.

Irrespective of what format my system datetime is set to (`dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` or any other format) and what format my datetime values is in the Excel sheet, I would be able to load it properly in SQL Server without any errors. Currently if my system datetime is `mm/dd/yyyy`, data is saved, but if I change system format to `dd/mm/yyyy`, the save operation fails.

**Save functionality:**

```
public int InsertSetting(DataRow drow)
    {
        int Result = 0;

        try
        {

            OdbcParameter[] p = new OdbcParameter[9];
            p[0] = new OdbcParameter("@ID", drow["ID"].ToString().Trim());
            p[1] = new OdbcParameter("@ComID", drow["CompanyID"].ToString().DbNullIfNullOrEmpty());
            p[2] = new OdbcParameter("@Mod", drow["ModuleID"].ToString().DbNullIfNullOrEmpty());
            p[3] = new OdbcParameter("@Stat", drow["Status"].ToString());
            p[4] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterBy", drow["EnterBy"].ToString().DbNullIfNullOrEmpty());
            p[5] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterDate", (drow["EnterDate"].ToString() == "" || drow["EnterDate"].ToString() == "NULL") ? (object)DBNull.Value : drow["EnterDate"].ToString());
            p[6] = new OdbcParameter("@UpdateBy", drow["UpdateBy"].ToString().DbNullIfNullOrEmpty());
            p[7] = new OdbcParameter("@UpdateDate", (drow["UpdateDate"].ToString() == "" || drow["UpdateDate"].ToString() == "NULL") ? (object)DBNull.Value : drow["UpdateDate"].ToString());
            p[8] = new OdbcParameter("@Mode", 7);


            Result = //calling stored procedure to save data

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "InsertSetting()");


        }
        return Result;

    }
```

Reading enterdate and updatedate in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I am not able to understand what exactly the problem is and what I have to do with system **Datetime** format.

Comment: Please **show us** your C# code to load the Excel sheet into SQL Server!

Comment: If your destination table want a date, then create a parameter of type date not a string. This is the source of all your problems

Comment: EnterDate  and UpdateDate are datetime parameters in procedure .They are not varchar in sp.

Comment: Have you tried `SET DATEFORMAT MDY;`

Comment: u want me to use SET DATEFORMAT MDY; in  sql server ?But my date value in excel can be any format and system date format can be anything..

Answer (score 0):

If `drow["EnterDate"]` and `drow["UpdateDate"]` are DateTime, you could enter a custom format in `ToString()`.

To save date into SQL Server via ADO.net, though I admit it is not a formal way, I found that it is always safer to format it to `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` regardless of local/server date time format settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming drow["EnterDate"] is string, you should convert date parameters to DateTime before passing to SQL Server. SQL Server treats date as MM/DD/YYYY if first part is 1 or 2 digits. Alternatively, you can pass dates as yyyyMMdd format.

With some simplification:

```
p[5] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterDate", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(drow["EnterDate"].ToString()) ? DateTime.Parse((string)drow["EnterDate"]) : DBNull.Value);
```

or

```
p[5] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterDate", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(drow["EnterDate"].ToString) ? DateTime.Parse((string)drow["EnterDate"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") : DBNull.Value);
```

If drow["EnterDate"] is already type of DateTime, then;

```
p[5] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterDate", drow["EnterDate"] != DBNull.Value ? (DateTime)drow["EnterDate"] : DBNull.Value);
```

or

```
p[5] = new OdbcParameter("@EnterDate", drow["EnterDate"] != DBNull.Value ? ((DateTime)drow["EnterDate"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") : DBNull.Value);
```